# Speed Up Predictions from R Model

Tags: r, optimization

I'm trying to write a simulation in R that involves making a bunch of predictions from a few different models (about 200 from a Negative binomial GLM and 5000 from a multinomial logit). These predictions are really bogging down my code and making it take a really long time to run. Is there anything I can do to speed up this prediction process?

Simplified example for the multinomial logit:

```
library(mnlogit)
library(mlogit)
data("Fishing", package = "mlogit")
Fish <- mlogit.data(Fishing, varying = c(2:9), shape = "wide", choice = "mode")
m <- mnlogit(mode ~price+ catch | income, data = Fish)
iterations <- 5000
for (i in (1:iterations)){
  newdata = data.frame("mode" = c("beach", "boat", "charter", "pier"), "price" = runif(4,15,150),
                       "catch" = runif(4,0,1), "income" = rep(runif(1,1500,7500),4))
  newdata<-mlogit.data(newdata, shape="long", choice="mode", alt.var="mode")
  prediction <- predict(m, newdata=newdata)
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to do 200 separate predictions from a model? Do all predictions at once and split the result as needed.

Comment: Each prediction depends on the previous one, so I need the results from one prediction to perform the next.

Comment: Then you are out of luck. You could try to write a faster predict function tailored to your specific model or implement everything in Rcpp.

Comment: what function are you using for multinomial logit? `nnet::multinom` ?

Comment: can you give a reproducible example please ... ?

Comment: I'm using `mnlogit`. I'll see if I can put together a concise example.